# Meteor HTTP get not working

Tags: javascript, http, meteor

I'm expecting to fetch a JSON data from the http request.
The `url` allows CORS connection and the commented out `url` also. In front-end there's one button in a template to call this method. it looks like from the console that it executes the function 'synchronously', but not getting expected result.
Here's my server side method

```
fetchFromService: function() {
   // var url = "http://googleplay-jsapi.herokuapp.com/app/com.meetsapp";

    var url = "https://play-fetch.herokuapp.com/app/com.opera.mini.native.beta";
    //synchronous GET
    var result = HTTP.get(url);
    if(result.statusCode==200) {
        var respJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
        console.log("response received.");
        return respJson;
    } else {
        console.log("Response issue: ", result.statusCode);
        var errorJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
        throw new Meteor.Error(result.statusCode, errorJson.error);
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is : 
[image]

the commented out url explicitly tells that it allows CORS request. still i deployed it to my own server. but i'm getting same error.

[Github link of the `url`](https://github.com/basiclines/GooglePlay-JSAPI)

I've also tried `Meteor.wrapAsync` also. it didn't work i out.

Comment: did you get any error message in the console?

Comment: sorry, forgot to upload the error message. doing it right now

Comment: Are you getting any response in the browser console after sometime?

Comment: i've not set any response in the browser. just a button. still browser should get internal server error.

Comment: can you try https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-the-http-package/?